# Jquery lightbox framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am building a new site and would like all the Add/Edit of new items to be in lightbox with ajax and i am using JQuery.
The lightbox should include on page validation in some cases, also should show the errors from server on form without submit or page refresh, the lightbox will have similar template (title, input fields and submit button) but the requirements and input fields will be different.
Another requirement will be to show loading icon while loading the lightbox and while doing the ajax.

My question is there already a solution for that?
If not how would you design it?
I started doing it with JQuery plugin to load the Form object and Inputs object array and create a template using Mustache, but this seems to be over complicated.

How other sites handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I would handle it by fetching JSON from the server and sending JSON to the server on form submit. Or in another format like [jQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on the forms.

You would render the form in the lightbox based upon the JSON you receive from the server. If the use clicks submit you'd send the data of the form in a JSON format to the server and have the server return any errors (or success).

Alternatively you could mirror the validation on the JavaScript side and only submit once JavaScript-side validation passes but that will close the popover.

I don't think this would be an exceptionally convoluted approach, though it might be if you are going to pull in plugins and other frameworks for this.